# Not able to execute a proc in oracle 10 g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am trying to execute a simple proc Like this in oracle 10g but not able to do getting error PLS-00905: object dbnew.sp_TDCCountry is invalid any idea would be appreciated
Table

```
CREATE TABLE TDCCountry
( CountryID number(10) NOT NULL,
  CountryName varchar2(50) NOT NULL  
);
```

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TDCCountry 
IS
BEGIN  
select * from tdcCountry;
COMMIT;
 END SP_TDCCountry;
```

Execution
1.

```
begin
   SP_TDCCountry;
  end;
```

2.`exec SP_TDCCountry;`

Comment: Plese [edit] your question and add the error message you got. But: you can't select something without storing it somewhere. What are you trying to do with that procedure? It select everything from a table but does not do anything with it. You have simplified the code to a point where the procedure is pretty much useless.

Comment: I have edited the question .i will use the value obtain through proc.

Answer (score 2):

Because you do not have an `into` clause by which you return values to some variables. It may be proper to return your variable as a `rowtype` [ By the way a commit is not needed for a `non-DDL`( in this case, there's a `SELECT`) statement ].

So, You may use in the following way :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TDCCountry IS
      v_row tdcCountry%rowtype;
BEGIN
      select * into v_row from tdcCountry;
      dbms_output.put(v_row.countryid||' - ');
      dbms_output.put_line(v_row.countryname);
END;
/
SQL> exec SP_TDCCountry;
```

If your `SELECT` statement brings more than one row, then it's proper to return data by means of `cursor` :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TDCCountry IS
      v_row tdcCountry%rowtype;
BEGIN
      for c in ( select * from tdcCountry )
      loop
       dbms_output.put(c.countryid||' - ');
       dbms_output.put_line(c.countryname);
      end loop; 
END;
/
SQL> exec SP_TDCCountry;
```

Comment: I have data already in tdcCountry and i want to fetch it through calling a proc in program  but through above proc which you mention again erro is coming after execution that "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows".

Comment: @Mohan ok, in that case(with `too_many_rows`), instead of `into`, it's proper to bring data by a cursor (I've just edited).